# Attempting to save values with core data but running into Error:"libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException"

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, option-type

Unable to save user input without running into this , the debugger says I'm successfully storing user input in my variables, but after starting the save action it crashes and points me to my

```
Class App Delegate: with "Thread 1 signal SIGABRT" error
```

and in the command line it says :

```
"libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException"
```

Here is the save action

```
 let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .default)
        { [unowned self] action in

            // find textfield's text (name) guard let way to get unwrap value otherwise return early*/

            guard let textField1 = alert.textFields?.first,
                let nameToSave = textField1.text else
            {
                    return
            }

            /*find textfield's text (size) guard let way to get unwrap value  otherwise return early*/

            guard let textField2 = alert.textFields?[1],
                let sizeToSave = textField2.text else
            {
                    return
            }

            // find textfield's text (contact) guard let way to get unwrap value otherwise return early*/

            guard let textField3 = alert.textFields?[2],
                let contactToSave = textField3.text else
            {
                return
            }

            guard let textField4 = alert.textFields?[3],
                let preferenceToSave = textField4.text else
            {
                return
            }


            //call save method by passing info
            self.save(name: nameToSave, size: Int16(sizeToSave)!, contact: Int32((contactToSave))!, seating: preferenceToSave)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
```

and here is the save function being called in the second to last line above

```
func save(name: String, size: Int16, contact: Int32, seating: String ) {
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
        }


        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Party", in: managedContext)!


        let party = NSManagedObject(entity: entity,
                                     insertInto: managedContext)

        party.setValue(name, forKeyPath: "name")
        party.setValue(size, forKeyPath: "size")
        party.setValue(contact, forKeyPath: "contact")
        party.setValue(seating, forKeyPath: "seating")

        do {
            try managedContext.save()
            parties.append(party)
            tableView.reloadData()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
```

If anything else needs to be provided that can help please let me know

Full Command Line:

```
2019-04-24 14:34:41.738429-0400 WaitUp[25353:1273717] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /Users/alexanderhoinville/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5623D759-E945-4844-9D55-CE708330A41F/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2019-04-24 14:34:41.739724-0400 WaitUp[25353:1273717] [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.
2019-04-24 14:34:51.330 WaitUp[25353:1273717] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3600.7.47/UITableView.m:8174
2019-04-24 14:34:51.366 WaitUp[25353:1273717] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView (<UITableView: 0x7ff5ef835800; frame = (0 64; 375 603); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x60000005fa40>; layer = <CALayer: 0x60800022b2a0>; contentOffset: {0, -64}; contentSize: {375, 44}>) failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource (<WaitUp.ViewController: 0x7ff5eec0e1d0>)'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010709fb0b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000104242141 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001070a3cf2 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
    3   Foundation                          0x0000000103ddc3b6 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 193
    4   UIKit                               0x0000000104c82fcf -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:] + 230
    5   UIKit                               0x0000000104c8e7b8 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 836
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000104c8e9a8 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 74
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000104c632e9 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 2845
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000104c9797c -[UITableView _performWithCachedTraitCollection:] + 111
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000104c7eb2a -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 233
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000104be520b -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1268
    11  QuartzCore                          0x0000000109e19904 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
    12  QuartzCore                          0x0000000109e0d526 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 370
    13  QuartzCore                          0x0000000109e0d3a0 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    14  QuartzCore                          0x0000000109d9ce92 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 294
    15  QuartzCore                          0x0000000109dc9130 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 468
    16  QuartzCore                          0x0000000109dc9b37 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 115
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107045717 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107045687 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010702a720 __CFRunLoopRun + 1200
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010702a016 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 406
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000108f5aa24 GSEventRunModal + 62
    22  UIKit                               0x0000000104b220d4 UIApplicationMain + 159
    23  WaitUp                              0x000000010383ed57 main + 55
    24  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000107fd965d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: Could you show the full error message. You should have a "Terminating with uncaught exception of type NSUncaughtException" (notice the "NSUncaughtException" vs "NSException".

Comment: added full log to post, thanks for quick reply! I can't find the line with NSUncaught, only NSException

Comment: forgive me, it was something wrong with my tableview, xcode was throwing me off pointing me somewhere else.To anyone that needs this, I just had to add UITableViewDataSource too the class definition. Thank you anyways!

Comment: That's also to point out that you'll find infos in the crash log/message, and that you didn't get the interesting part: "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView (; layer = ; contentOffset: {0, -64}; contentSize: {375, 44}>) failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource ()" ;)